# Bind to DependencyProperty of Type Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Programmers,
i have the need to change an ItemsSource Binding at runtime.
In my DataGrid i want to see items of Type "Akte".
This code in the ViewModel works:

```
    #region DependencyProperty AktenDataGrid
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AktenDataGridProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AktenDataGrid", typeof(DataGrid), typeof(UebersichtVM));

    public DataGrid AktenDataGrid
    {
        get { return (DataGrid)GetValue(AktenDataGridProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AktenDataGridProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion DependencyProperty AktenDataGrid

    private void OnSammelakteChangedCommand(object parameter)
    {
        Binding aktenBinding;

        if (null == AktenDataGrid || null == parameter)
        {
            aktenBinding = new Binding("AngemeldeterBenutzer.AktenBenutzer");
        }
        else
        {
            aktenBinding = new Binding("SelectedItem.Sammelakte.SammelakteAkten");
            aktenBinding.ElementName = "sammelaktenDataGrid";
        }

        AktenDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, aktenBinding);
    }
```

The command is executed by changing the selection in my sammelaktenDataGrid.
It is necessary to initialize the Property AktenDataGrid with the affected DataGrid in Code-Behind of my UserControl.

I want to Change my ViewModel in the way, that it provides a DependencyProperty AktenDataGridBinding of Type Binding and i want to bind ItemSource to this Property.
I tried it out, but it doesn't work.
Can you help me?

Comment: I can imagine the amount of people now copy/pasting @MarkusHütter's comment into Google Translate... :) - FYI, it translates (not very well) to English: "Tip: I would always program in English . So classes / variable / function names . Makes it easier , the non-German speaking people understand your code"

Comment: @Markus Another small tip, comments on StackOverflow (as questions and answers) should *always be in english* so that anybody can follow.

Comment: Haha, sorry about that =)

Comment: Don't put code into the CLR wrapper of dependency properties.

Comment: As H.B. said, you should not put code except GetValue/SetValue in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The reason is explained in the MSDN article [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.100).aspx). In this special case it is even entirely redundant, because you don't need to raise a PropertyChanged event for dependency properties. They come with their own change notification mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps this is it:

This will show `SelectedItem.Sammelakte.SammelakteAkten` within the `DataGrid` unless it is `null`, in which case it will show `AngemeldeterBenutzer.AktenBenutzer`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Sammelakte.SammelakteAkten, ElementName=sammelaktenDataGrid}">
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Sammelakte.SammelakteAkten}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=AngemeldeterBenutzer.AktenBenutzer}" />
                </DataTrigger>                                     
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>            
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I tried some variations incl. changing the bindings an changing the comparisationvalue to x:Type. It seems, that nothing is triggered.